# Displaying error message box only if an input file is in an incorrect format

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently writing a script for a GUI where a user can specify input files and an output folder. The process that this GUI feeds into requires .csv files for it to work. I have an error message prompt for if the input files do not end in csv, but would like assistance to adapt it so that the error message box only shows once the user has chosen a file and ideally before they click the calculate button if the file format is wrong.

```
if not main.sourceFilea.endswith('.csv') :
    messagebox.showerror("Input File Error", "Input Equation File must be a .csv file")      
if not main.sourceFileb.endswith('.csv'):
    messagebox.showerror("Input File Error", "Input Variant File must be a .csv file")
main.mainloop()
```

For reference this is the full GUI script I have thus far. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

main = tkinter.Tk()
main.title('Load Combination Software')
main.geometry("1200x300")
main.sourceFilea = ''
main.sourceFileb = ''
main.eq_num = ''
main.outputfolder = ''

def chooseFilea():
    main.sourceFilea =  filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=main, initialdir= "/", title='Please select input equations')
    pathlabela.config(text=main.sourceFilea)

b_chooseFilea = tkinter.Button(main, text = "Browse", width = 10, height = 1, command = chooseFilea)
b_chooseFilea.place(x = 1050,y = 50)
pathlabela = tkinter.Label(main, bg='white')
pathlabela.place(x=50,y=50,height=25,width=1000)
titlea= tkinter.Label(main, text= 'Select Input Equation File' )
titlea.place(x=50,y=30)

def chooseFileb():
    main.sourceFileb = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=main, initialdir= "/", title='Please select input variants')
    pathlabelb.config(text=main.sourceFileb)

b_chooseFileb = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'Browse', width = 10, height = 1, command = chooseFileb)
b_chooseFileb.place(x = 1050,y = 100)
pathlabelb = tkinter.Label(main, bg='white')
pathlabelb.place(x=50,y=100,height=25,width=1000)
titleb= tkinter.Label(main, text= "Select Variant Input File" )
titleb.place(x=50,y=80)



def chooseDir():
    main.outputfolder =  filedialog.askdirectory(parent=main, initialdir= "/", title='Please select a directory')
    pathlabelc.config(text=main.outputfolder)

b_outputfolder = tkinter.Button(main, text = "Browse", width = 10, height = 1, command = chooseDir)
b_outputfolder.place(x = 1050,y = 150)
pathlabelc = tkinter.Label(main, bg='white')
pathlabelc.place(x=50,y=150,height=25,width=1000)
titlec= tkinter.Label(main, text= "Select Output Folder" )
titlec.place(x=50,y=130)

b_calc = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'Calculate and Quit', width = 45, height = 5, command=main.destroy)
b_calc.place(x=450,y=200)


if not main.sourceFilea.endswith('.csv') :
    messagebox.showerror("Input File Error", "Input Equation File must be a .csv file")      
if not main.sourceFileb.endswith('.csv'):
    messagebox.showerror("Input File Error", "Input Variant File must be a .csv file")
main.mainloop()

print(main.sourceFilea)
print(main.sourceFileb)
print(main.outputfolder)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to specifically state what file you accept in the file picker?

Comment: Okay so you can pass this `filetypes` argument to `.askopenfilename`: `filetypes = (("CSV files","*.csv"))`. It will now only let you choose CSV files, so you can eliminate that validation step. However note that files that are *not* CSV-structured can still be opened if someone were to change the file ending of a different type file to `.csv`

Comment: See here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm

Comment: Passing the filetype argument seems to break the button command for some reason. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: It worked when I passed the argument as filetypes= [("CSV files","*.csv"]. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah yes it was supposed to be a list of tuples not a tuple of tuples. Glad to help!